# SSIS Row Count with Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have Product table have Productid  and Product_No as Primary key. Now when I process the rows and filter it in Black,Blue,Red,white color category. I know How to filter it but the problem is I have to update the row counts in another table Product_Category(Product_Id as PK). but I have update according to Product_DI.

Explanation:-Filtering Product table with Black color
Product table

```
Product_ID | Product_No | Price | Color
1          | 1          | 2.50  | Black
1          | 2          | 0.96  | Black
1          | 3          | 0.96  | Black
1          | 4          | 0.96  | Black
2          | 1          | 0.96  | Black
2          | 2          | 0.96  | Black
3          | 1          | 0.96  | Black
```

SO I have to update the Product_Category

```
Product_ID | Color_CNT
1          | 4
2          | 2
3          | 1
```

Please share your knowledge. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am missing something with your question, you can just run an `UPDATE` against your second table, using the first:

```
update t2
set Color_CNT = ColorCount
from table2 t2
left join
(
  select count(color) ColorCount, Product_ID
  from table1
  group by Product_ID
) t1
  on t2.product_id = t1.product_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9752b/3)

If you need to `INSERT` the data, then you can do the following:

```
insert into table2 (product_id, color_cnt)
select Product_ID,  count(color) ColorCount
from table1
group by Product_ID;
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5aeaa/3)

Both of these can be done in SSIS, you will create an `Execute SQL Task` and place the query inside of the SQL statement field.  This will then be executed when your package runs.

Comment: @343 you can execute sql in SSIS, use an execute SQL task

Comment: Hi,I am new and I took Row Count variable for each case and through row count I have Update my table.I tried with your statement but I wont be update. please give me solution in ssis.

Comment: It is a solution for SSIS, from the toolbox, add an `Execute SQL Task`, you will place the query in the SQL Statement with no result set coming back.

Comment: Thans for your help both the solution didn't work in my scenario...Here I put example same as my requirement. I have to perform this with Row count each wise (using for each loop ) and at the end it will Update the Product category table with each count.

Comment: @343 then you should be able to just add an execute sql task to update the table with the rowcount